# how can I install pspell in php5/ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, aspell

I am trying to install pspell for PHP 5 in Ubuntu. I have installed the aspell library which is required to run pspell as shown [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pspell.requirements.php)

I am not sure if there are any settings I need to change, etc.

When I try to execute the below mentioned line of code

`$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");`

I get an error

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function pspell_new()`

Any idea on what could be wrong ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should this be on Server fault?

Comment: Definitely not Server Fault, since I don't think it deals with "networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs."  It might be answered on Super User, but I think the best fit is here on SO.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

just do

```
sudo apt-get install libpspell-dev 
sudo apt-get install php5-pspell
sudo apt-get install aspell-en
```

then restart your apache2 server with the following command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

it will be added automatically to your php.ini

you can try this [example](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ref.pspell.php#78609)

Comment: You may need to replace "services" with just "service" as I did.

Comment: For PHP7, change to **php7-pspell**

Comment: @KohjahBreese on v16.04 this covers php7 as well: `apt install php-pspell` -> `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-pspell php7.0-pspell`

Comment: I have PHP 5.6 and I got `E: Package 'php5-pspell' has no installation candidate` and then I run `sudo apt-get install php5.6-pspell` command and it worked

Answer (score 1):

For those using PHP 7.2 / Ubuntu 18.10, here is what I did to get PSPELL working:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pspell
sudo apt-get install php-pspell
sudo apt-get install aspell-en
sudo apt-get install aspell-fr
sudo apt-get install aspell-de
sudo apt-get install aspell-es
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I use multiple languages, so included some of them in the example above. I believe EN is included by default.

Answer (score 0):

"I have installed the aspell library which is required to run pspell as shown here"

- that's if you compile your own PHP - did you recompile with pspell?

Note that this package just provides the API and data, you are getting an error becuase your PHP doesn't know how to interface with it.

If you're not into building your own code, the PHP extension is available as a package:

(NB this is JUST the PHP side of the service)

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/dapper/php-pspell

C.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured php.ini to load the extension?