# pspell source install with source installed php5.6

Tags: php, tar, pear, pecl, pspell

I am trying to enable the php pspell module with source installed php5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

**Methods I have tried :**

1. While ./configure in downloaded php package I tried --with-pspell=/usr and --with-pspell.

But this didn't work.

2. pecl search pspell.

But failed to find any pspell related packages.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu : 14.04.
I'll update that in question as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957808/how-can-i-install-pspell-in-php5-ubuntu

Comment: I know about this.
But if you do apt-cache show php-pspell.
It will show that php5.9-pspell will be installed.
But I want php5.6-pspell that too with source installed php.

Comment: Have you configured php.ini to load the extension?

Comment: I assume by that you mean .so files.
Yes, it is configured for that.
But how do I get .so file for pspell ?

Comment: can you just run `info()`. And check whether the extension loaded or not.

Comment: I tried, php -m | grep -i "pspell"
But failed to find any pspell module enabled.

Comment: After installation, did you restart the apache2?

Comment: Yes, I restarted apache after installation.

Comment: uninstall and purge this package. try with these `sudo apt-get install libpspell-dev  
sudo apt-get install php5-pspell 
sudo apt-get install aspell-en` and finally `sudo service apache2 restart `

Comment: Please do apt-cache show php-pspell
It is for php5.9.
Even if I add repo of php5.6, then I do php5.6-pspell installation then additional php5.6 packages will be installed, which is something I don't want.
I have installed everything using tar file of php5.6, so I want every module to be source install or pecl installed if possible.